# HTTP get request with Angular 5 and NodeJS

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I have 3 years experience in web development, but have always used MVC under the .NET framework. Recently I have started development on a MEAN stack project, but have come to a point where I need more training or help.
Currently, I am able to make get and post requests successfully, but I am having trouble making a get request when I need to get an item by ID. 
Following is the code I am using.

**nodeJS code**

This, I believe, is correct on the back end. I think I am having problems on the Angular side, but will share this code in case.

**Router:**

```
router.get('/userProfile/:id', auth, ctrlProfile.userProfileRead);
```

**Controller:**

```
module.exports.userProfileRead = function(req, res, next) {
  const id = req.params.id
  User.findById(id)
  .select(fields)
  .exec()
  .then((result) => {
    const response = {
      count: result.length,
      data: result.map((result) => {
        return {
          id: result._id,
          firstname: result.firstname,
          lastname: result.lastname,
          email: result.email,
          username: result.username
        }
      })
    };
    if (result.length > 0) {
      res.status(200).json(response)
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({
        message: `Successfully fetched ${route_name}s. However, no ${route_name}s have been created.`
      })
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({
      error: err
    });
  });
};
```

**Angular 5 code**

This is what I believe is my problem child.

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService, UserDetails } from './authentication.service';
import { UserProfile } from './models/UserProfile';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  userDetails: UserDetails;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, public auth: AuthenticationService) { 
this.userDetails = auth.getUserDetails();
 }

  getUserProfile(id: string): Observable<UserProfile> {
return this.http.get<UserProfile>(`/api/userProfile/${id}`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}` }});
  }
}
```

**Proxy Configuration**

```
{
  "/api": {
"target": "http://localhost:3000",
"secure": false
  }

    }
```

I apologize if the code formatting is poor. I am new to asking questions on stack overflow, but this one has me stumped and I haven't been able to find any information online as to why this is not working for me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The issue I am having is that when I am able to hit the endpoint, the request times out and I get a console error of 'unknown url'.

**EDIT:**

Here is the working code. The only difference in my request is that I am not sending parameters.

**nodeJS**

**Router:**

```
router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login);
```

**Controller:**

```
module.exports.login = function(req, res) {

if (req.body.ActiveDirectory)
  {
passport.authenticate('ldapauth', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.status(200).json({ "message": "worked" })
}
  }

  else
  {
passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
  var token;


  // If Passport throws/catches an error
  if (err) {
    res.status(404).json(err);
    return;
  }

  // If a user is found
  if(user){
    token = user.generateJwt();
    res.status(200);
    res.json({
      "token" : token
    });
  } else {
    // If user is not found
    res.status(401).json(info);
  }
})(req, res);
  }

};
```

**Angular5**

**Service:**

```
  private request(method: 'post'|'get', type: 'login'|'register'|'profile'|'userProfile', user?: TokenPayload): Observable<any> {
let base;

if (method === 'post') 
{
  base = this.http.post(`/api/${type}`, user);
} 
else 
{
  base = this.http.get(`/api/${type}`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` }});
}

const request = base.pipe(
  map((data: TokenResponse) => {
    if (data.token) {
      this.saveToken(data.token);
    }
    return data;
  })
);

return request;
  }
```

Comment: Okay but what is the issue?

Comment: When I send the request, there are times when it will not even hit the endpoint. However, when it does hit the endpoint, the request is pending, times out, and gives an error of 'unknown url'.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a valid URL. In your case, you should prepend `http://localhost:3000` to the URLs you are currently using:

`http://localhost:3000/api/userProfile/${id}`

Comment: My proxy configuration is rerouting to localhost:3000 for me. I am able to successfully do get a posts, but not when I am sending parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Express v4, I do not believe router.get() accepts more than 2 parameters. If you are using middleware for your auth, app.use() is where that would be appropriate.

[Router](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router)

[App.use](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use)

Also, your router registers `/userProfile/:id` instead of `/api/userProfile/:id` which is what your angular code is calling. Are you prefixing `/api` somewhere else?

Comment: I am using Express 4.15.3. Just tried removing the auth parameter, but still no luck.

Comment: If you look at my most recent edit of the code that is working, I am simply routing to /login and getting the response I need.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, once we return the http request variable the calling component needed to "subscribe" to the request in order to receive the data.

```
this.data.profile(this.userDetails._id).subscribe(user => {
        this.userProfile = user;
      }, (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });;
```

Also the parameters needed to be passed in a different way in the http base request.

```
this.http.get(`/api/${type}`, { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.getToken()}` }, params: { params }});
```